# Jquery:create a dictionary to autocomplete all inputs

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-autocomplete

i want to add an smart autocomplete to my project in which when ever user is typing a word in any input its autocompleted from his own dictionary.

his owner dictionary is built by saving every word he ever submit to server something like (array_values($_POST))

my current JS

```
$('input.complete').live('keyup.autocomplete', function(){
        var hi=$(this).val().toUpperCase();
        var was=this;
        $(this).autocomplete({
//PROBLEM Should i consider to change source from ajax/mysql to different source ?
//since there gona be too many requests ??
            source: function(request, response) {
                    $.ajax({ url: '<?=base_url()?>ajax/ac',
//PROBLEM how can i set term=word currently being edited..(start=' ',end=pointerpos)
                    data: { 'term': this.term },
                    dataType: "json",
                    type: "POST",
                    success: function(data){
                        if(data.length){
                            //response(data);
          //Commented out cause i dont wana display dropdown.. just typeahead.
                              if(data[0]['value'].substr(0,hi.length).toUpperCase()==hi){
                                $(was).val(data[0]['value']);
//currently working with single word inputs..once i get how to select only current word will edit these..
                                was.selectionStart=hi.length;
                                was.selectionEnd=data[0]['value'].length;   
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
            },
            select: function(event, ui){},
            minLength: 2,
            delay: 500
        });
```

As u can see i have 2 problems

**Question**

1. how can i select current word that user is typing ?
2. is this a good approach to reach my goal, or i should consider different plugin

Comment: [select2](http://ivaynberg.github.com/select2/) is a great select/autocomplete plugin with lots of configuration options.

Answer (score -1):

You are using PHP language as well. So in my opinion you can use PHP to solve your problem more easily. Let's say you have php function get_word($excerpt) in get.php file. So,

```
<?php
     get_word($_POST['excerpt']);
     function get_word($excerpt) {
          // Find exact word from database or array using given $excerpt
          // and return complete word.
          return $complete_word;
     }
?>
```

And in your jquery (assuming input field as .input),

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $('.input').live('keyup',function() {
          var excerpt = $(this).val();
          $.post("get.php", {excerpt:excerpt}, function(data) {
               // do anything with data.
               $('.input').val(data);
          });
     });
})
```

For more precise, you can get bunch of matching words from get.php file, and display list of words to be selected.

Comment: need js to figure out the word that user is currently typing so that php can complete

Comment: @MomenMElZalabany, I can't understand the problem. Let's say user types "Ap" in input. So, js code activated, and set "Ap" in variable excerpt. Then, it sends "Ap" to get.php page.

On, get.php page, function get_word() receives "Ap", and check database for words similar to "Ap". Let's say it founds "Apple". It returns "Apple" as data to js code.


Then again using js, data (Apple) can be set to input field using, $('.input).val(data);